# How to create a function to get an Auth0 token

Tags: javascript, function, automated-tests, auth0, cypress

I’m trying to create a function to get a login token from Auth0 for a user for so I don’t have to use the login test before every test scenario (which isn’t working anyway), but rather I want to have a stored token and use that to authenticate the user so I can test the application.
I’m not a developer (or even a developer in Test).  I’m a QA who is trying to learn enough Javascript in order to use Cypress to create test scenarios for our new internal risk assessment application.
We have a list of users for our new app which will all be verified through Auth0.  All the users are internal to our company and are based on our emails which are linked to Microsoft accounts.

Below is my login test that presses the login button, which is then redirected to Auth0 and then enters my email address to verify the login.  This is successful except for the fact that it doesn’t actually load the application.

````
```
    describe('My Login Test', function (){
    it('Visit Risk App Landing Page', function (){
        const typedText = 'adam.allford@landmark.co.uk'
        cy.visit('https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net')
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').first()
        .type(typedText)
        .should('have.value', typedText)
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.url().should('eq','http://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net/workflow')
         })
    })
```
````

I had a reply on a Gitter forum from someone who had a similar issue and used what is displayed below (or similar) to try and login.  I edited it with relevant details for what I need and put this in the command.js with a loginuser.json (containing username and password) in the shown loacation, and then included the beforeEach in a test scenario.

````
```

    Cypress.Commands.add('login', (userType, options = {}) => 
    {cy.readFile(`cypress/fixtures/loginUser.json`).then((json) => {
    const { email, password } = json
       const dataToSend = {
           email,
           password,
       }
       cy.request({
           url: `https://lmcorp.eu.auth0.com/userinfo`,
           method: 'POST',
           body: dataToSend,
           form: true
       }).then((response) => {
           const { status, body } = response
           expect(status).to.eq(200)
           expect(body).to.have.property('success', 1)
           cy.visit(url)
      })
    })

    //and use it like :
    beforeEach(() => { login('url') })
```
````

… and then included the beforeEach in a test scenario.

````
```
    describe('My First Test', function (){
    it('Visit Risk App Landing Page', function (){
        beforeEach(() => { login('https://lmcorp.eu.auth0.com/')})
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/workflow')
        cy.contains('Site Solutions Combined Assessments')
        cy.contains('To Do')
        cy.contains('Assessing')
        cy.contains('Reviewing')
        cy.contains('Done')
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.contains('Assessments')
        cy.contains('Site Solutions Combined')
        cy.contains('Flood')
        cy.contains('Whatever Next')
    })
    })

```
````

But I get the following message on the command console.

![alt]https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU7Hp.png

I’m completely stuck and don’t know where to go from here.  My question is:   I want to create a feature that will call our Auth0 url and get a login authentication token, which can be used to allow access the application for every test scenario.  Can I change what I have here to make that work, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to create a new feature to get an Auth0 token?

Comment: May not change things, but `beforeEach()` is usually placed outside the `it()`.

Comment: Also, run the steps manually and take a look at the inherent delays, e.g does the login seem to take half a second. If so, add a `cy.wait(500)` after the login command (play around with the duration).

Comment: Hi Richard,  Thanks for your comments.  Moving the before each has made a change in that I'm now getting a message stating that "login" is not defined.  So I can work on that.  Adding a timeout however has made no difference to the login test.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. This may not be always the case, but examples of `Cypress.Commands.add(...` I have seen use the command in a chained or fluent manner (like `.type()`, `.should()`). You may just want a plain JS function for `login` instead of a command. Could you please link the Gitter forum where the idea came from?

Comment: Hi. https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress  This is the Gitter forum where the idea was suggested, although that was a couple of weeks ago now so finding the post may prove difficult.